# Hello i got an assignment in c programing and i dont really understand the c/malloc function i think

Tags: c

Hello i got an assignment in c programing and i dont really understand the c/malloc function i think,
they told us that we need to do the free function after using this function, but every time i do free it breaks the program

The assignment is :

collect an input string.

1. every upper case letter to lower
2. every lower case letter to upper
3. if there is number do series of numbers from '9' until the input number but with out it (for '6' do '9','8','7'. (with out 6))
4. if there is other stuff don't add it in to the out put.

input example : A$q6#G4
output example : aQ987g98765

- it is not allowed to change the input string.
- in the input allowed to be every thing.
- the output sting needs to be exactly in the array size
  (if 123 = the size of will be input[2])

photo of the error
[image]
the error : wntdll.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module ntdll.dll

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
/* Function declarations */
char Ex1FNumbers(char);
char Ex1FLetters(char);
/* ------------------------------- */

// 
int main()
{
    system("cls"); //delete when send
    int select = 0, i, all_Ex_in_loop = 0;
    printf("Run menu once or cyclically?\n(Once - enter 0, cyclically - enter other number) ");
    if (scanf_s("%d", &all_Ex_in_loop) == 1)
        do
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
                printf("Ex%d--->%d\n", i, i);
            printf("EXIT-->0\n");
            do {
                select = 0;
                printf("please select 0-3 : ");
                scanf_s("%d", &select);
            } while ((select < 0) || (select > 3));
            switch (select)
            {
            case 1:     //Ex1
            {
                int size, i, n, counter = 0;
                char inPut[] = "";
                char outPut[] = "";
                char* Ptr_inPut_address, * Ptr_outPut_address, num;
                printf("Please enter a string :\n");
                scanf("%s", inPut); 
                size = strlen(inPut);
                Ptr_outPut_address = &outPut;
                Ptr_inPut_address   = (char*) calloc(size+1 , sizeof(char));
                Ptr_outPut_address  = (char*) calloc(0, sizeof(char));
                if (!Ptr_inPut_address || !Ptr_outPut_address)
                {
                    break;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    Ptr_outPut_address = (char*)realloc(Ptr_outPut_address, counter);
                    if (inPut[i] >= 'a' && inPut[i] <= 'z' || inPut[i] >= 'A' && inPut[i] <= 'Z')
                    {
                        if (inPut[i] >= 'a' && inPut[i] <= 'z')
                        {
                            outPut[counter++]  = inPut[i] - 32;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            outPut[counter++] = inPut[i] + 32;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (inPut[i] <= '9' && inPut[i] >= '0')
                    {
                        n = '9' - inPut[i];
                        Ptr_outPut_address = (char*)realloc(Ptr_outPut_address, counter + n);
                        for (n; n > 0; n--) // "o" of 8 and not "n" because 8 is the max num for this "for".
                        {
                            outPut[counter++] = inPut[i] + n;
                        }       
                    }
                }
                Ptr_outPut_address = (char*)realloc(Ptr_outPut_address, counter);
                outPut[counter] = '\0';
                
                Ptr_outPut_address = &outPut;
                printf("%s\n", Ptr_outPut_address);
                if (Ptr_outPut_address != NULL)
                {
                    free(Ptr_outPut_address);
                }
                if (Ptr_inPut_address != NULL)
                {
                    free(Ptr_inPut_address);
                }
            } break;
            case 2:     //Ex2
            {               

            }break;
            case 3:     //Ex3
            {

            }break;
            }
        } while (all_Ex_in_loop && select);
        system("pause");//delete when send
        main();//delete when send
        //return 0; // return when send

}
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 Where did you find that `malloc`?

Comment: Well it's calloc or realloc actually.

Comment: Are you recursively invoking `main()` from itself (from the last line)?

Answer (score 3):

```
            char inPut[] = "";
            char outPut[] = "";
```

This declares two arrays that contain exactly one `char`, initializing them to `'\0'`. That's what the above means in C. This does not mean that these two arrays will have infinite size and can store any string. That's not how this works. But then, immediately afterwards:

```
            scanf("%s", inPut);
```

This is guaranteed to overflow the array, since it is capable of holding only one `char`. Any string this reads will have at least two `char`s: the single read character, followed by `'\0'`. This results in memory corruption and undefined behavior.

There are several other bugs in the shown code. One more example:

```
 Ptr_outPut_address = &outPut;
```

This has the effect of setting this variable to the starting address of a `char` array that was declared earlier.

```
 Ptr_outPut_address = (char*)realloc(Ptr_outPut_address, counter);
```

You can only `realloc` something that was `malloc`ed, `realloc`ed, or `calloc`ed. No exceptions. You cannot `realloc` anything else. The `char` array was not `malloc`ed, `realloc`ed, or `calloc`ed. C does not work this way.

Several other problems exists in the shown code. Looks like this entire program was written all at once, before an attempt was made to test everything. This approach is very unlikely to succeed, and will likely produce many different kinds of bugs, such as the one that I've described. This makes it difficult to analyze and fix everything, since you're not looking for just one bug, but an unknown number of bugs. Plus it is likely that there will be an eventual realization that some or most of what was written need to be rewritten from scratch since the shown approach turned out to be fundamentally wrong.

Which is what you should probably do: start from scratch, write only a few lines of code, before testing them, and making sure that they work correctly before proceeding to write more code. If you attempt to fix just the problems that I explained it's likely that this will just create other problems, additionally, there are other problems as well, I just didn't mention them. The entire approach that was used here needs to be changed, fundamentally.

Comment: Hello sam, thank you for the help.

Im really new to c programing language,
I didnt understand when and where I need to declare the malloc and calloc.
is there any way to explain this part ? or an article about this topic I tried to look in google but didnt understand in what part of the code I need to use it.
(before collecting the string or after)

Comment: You should not be looking at Google, but at a good textbook. C and C++ are two of the most complicated general purpose programming languages in use today. You cannot learn them from Google searches, or Youtube videos, or random web sites. The explanation you're looking for takes up at least a chapter in an average C textbook. It's unrealistic to copy/paste an entire chapter here, of course. There is no alternative to a good textbook, when learning C or C++.

Comment: @cc4dayz - I don't disagree with other comment but in a nutshell calloc()/malloc()/realloc() are used to allocate memory when the size of the object (whether it be a simple array or  array of struct or a new list item etc) is not known at runtime.  If the size of an object is known at compile time dynamic memory allocation is not needed.

Comment: @ryyker *"... when the size of the object ... is not known at [compile time]."* - what you meant, surely? In other words, *"`*alloc` is used when the size of an object is determined at a runtime"*. (Can of worms too, because sometime you just want heap memory even if you know the the size at compile time. Comment section not a great place to learn the nuance of memory allocation - easy to cause confusion. Hence: a good C textbook.)